# Border issue in word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, border

When I open an existing doc or create new one, the program always open with borders live below:

[image]

Can you help guide me how to hide the borders?

Comment: To clarify, new documents open with a table? If so, just rename the current normal.dotm file (see here for step by step: https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/fix-word-2016-normal-template/) and restart Word and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for your message, Karen. I was able to solve the issue by "Uncheck" the option "Show text boundaries" in Word Options/Advanced/Show document content